# Product Discount Show and Hide Error in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to display the discount percent and Original Price(it is strike out) only if the discount percent is greater than 0.I am getting both values dynamically from server for that i use ngFor loop.I just bind it in my html.
To achieve this i used *ngIf directive.But it shows all the discount values even if it is zero.How to achieve this using ngIf. 
Anyone help with this. Thanks in Advance..[I don't want to display the 0% discount as well as the strike out price.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS8cj.jpg)

My component.html is:

```
<div *ngIf="discountPercent!==0">
    <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let product of productList">
      <figure class="card card-product"> 
        <div class="starburst discount" id="star" #rotateEl>
          <span></span>
          <span>{{product.Discount}}%</span>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wrap">
       <a routerLink="/product-details"><img src="assets/{{ product.Image }}"></a>  
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
        <div class="block-ellipsis">
          <span>{{product.ProductName}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="bottom-wrap">
          <div class="price-wrap h5">
            <span class="price-new">Rs.{{product.DiscountedPrice}}</span> &nbsp;
            <del class="price-old">Rs.{{product.OriginalPrice}}</del>
          </div>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My component.ts file is:

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
    discountPercent = 0;
     ngOnInit() {
        this.productsService.getProducts()
        .then((response:Response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.productList = response;
          this.discountPercent = this.productList.Discount;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you check in console.log(this.discountPercent) what it prints after initialization?

Comment: It remains same after initialization

Comment: Can you try <div *ngIf="discountPercent!=0"> ??

Comment: yeah,i had tried it. but my expected result no came

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `discountPercent` variable is not necessary. Just try this.

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let product of productList">
  <figure class="card card-product"> 
    <div *ngIf="product.Discount" class="starburst discount" id="star" #rotateEl>
      <span></span>
      <span>{{product.Discount}}%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrap">
   <a routerLink="/product-details"><img src="assets/{{ product.Image }}"></a>  
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
    <div class="block-ellipsis">
      <span>{{product.ProductName}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="bottom-wrap">
      <div class="price-wrap h5">
        <span class="price-new">Rs.{{product.DiscountedPrice}}</span> &nbsp;
        <del *ngIf="product.Discount" class="price-old">Rs.{{product.OriginalPrice}}</del>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: @Arthi Good to hear it is working. You can mark the answer as correct, if it fixed your problem.

Comment: Yeah i did it Once again Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

In your component,

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
    discountPercent = 0;
    discountPercentBool:boolean;            // add bool variable
     ngOnInit() {
        this.discountPercentBool = false;   // default value on init
        this.productsService.getProducts()
        .then((response:Response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.productList = response;
          if(this.productList.Discount>0){
             discountPercentBool = true;   // initialize vaule after api call
          }

        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
}
```

In your view,

```
<div *ngIf="discountPercentBool">
```

Comment: yeah. because this.productList.Discount is 0. only when it is greater than 0, products will be shown. I believe thats what you needed. Am I missing something?